# Marketing analytics texts

Tags: references, marketing

Can you recommend a comprehensive textbook or a monograph on marketing analytics?

I'm interested in metrics, measures and statistical methods used in the field. For instance, what are the approaches at companies like Amazon and Walmart?

UPDATE:
I'm looking for a text like Greene, [Econometric Analysis](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~wgreene/Text/econometricanalysis.htm). Econometrics is a set of statistical methods applied to economics. So, I want the same but for Marketing. I'm not interested in technology aspects, because that's the same everywhere: big data, databases etc.

Comment: What is your quantitative background? Generally speaking, I think that it would be useful to learn regression, time series analysis, and other statistical methods. 

Marketing Analytics = Statistics + SQL programming + business insights

Comment: @cwh_UCF, my background is econometrics + theor physics + programming

Answer (score 0):

With your background, I would recommend that you learn statistics and SQL programming. For the statistics, learn linear regression, logistic regression, time series analysis, decision trees, and some machine learning (random forests, neural nets, boosting, etc.) For the SQL programming, you can buy a book and learn using fake data, but SQL programming is a skill that is best learned on the job using real (**messy**) data.

Answer (score -1):

[Marketing Strategy: Based on First Principles and Data Analytics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1137526238) is a great resource for what you're looking for in relation to marketing and data analytics.